Ошибка unknown system variable license в MySql
Подскажите пожалуйста, в C# пытаюсь подключиться к базе данные, на что получаю ошибку unknown system variable license. Что делать? Вот код:
string connstr = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=db1";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connstr;
conn.Open();
string query = $"INSERT INTO post_pr (tn,fm,ima,oth) VALUES ('@v1','@v2','@v3','@v4')";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v2", textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v3", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v4", textBox4.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

Ошибка возникает на строчке:
conn.Open();

Вот ошибка:

Вот код:


Покажите полный трейс ошибки.

Вы хотя бы укажите, в какой именно строке кода возникает ошибка...

@Akina поправил

VALUES ('@v1','@v2','@v3','@v4') А одиночные кавычки тут точно нужны? Попробуйте без них. Скорее всего они лишние. Хотя к ошибке это вроде не имеет отношения. Просто значения не подставятся.


Если ошибка возникает в указанной строке, то весь следующий код совершенно не нужен, и его можно удалить. 2. Покажите ТОЧНЫЙ текст ошибки - вплоть до мест перевода строк. Можно даже скриншотом. 3. Перед проблемной строкой запросите/получите ВСЕ параметры созданного объекта conn и проверьте их на корректность.


@CrazyElf, не помогло

не помогло ??? предполагалось, что полный трейс будет выложен в текст вопроса...

@Anton Конечно, это пока не поможет. То что я написал поможет потом, когда вы с коннекшеном разберётесь и у вас вместо реальных значений будут записываться в базу '@v1','@v2','@v3','@v4'

А вообще пока вы не предоставите ПОЛНЫЙ ТРЕЙС ОШИБКИ, хотя бы скриншотом - это всё гадание на кофейной гуще.

@CrazyElf, я предоставил скриншоты ошибки

Ну хорошо. А сами системные переменные MySql смотрели, есть там license? Попробуйте её убрать, например. Куда-нибудь скопировав предварительно.

@CrazyElf, зашел в переменные, слова license там даже нет

https://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SHOW_VARIABLES.html

@CrazyElf, я с этой базой на python работал, проблем никаких не было

Ну там надо разбираться, возможно та версия коннектора, которую вы используете, не совместима с чем-нибудь. Вам нужно написать в вопросе какая у вас версия .NET, какая версия библиотеки для коннекта к MySQL, какая версия самого MySQL и дальше копать совместимы они все между собой или нет. Это боль, но судя по беглому гуглению простого решения нет. Попробуйте библиотеку посвежее поставить, если есть.

@CrazyElf, насколько я знаю стоит mysql4, древняя версия

стоит mysql4, древняя версия Системная переменная license появилась в версии 5.0. Обновляйте сервер или ищите древний коннектор, буде он вообще существует.

MySQL сервер обновите.

Нашел решение: install-package mysql.data -Version 6.2.5.0
